# Создать jar с помощью Maven без groupId и version

Tags: maven

Всем привет. Появилась необходимость создать jar с помощью Maven без groupId и version. Как всем известно уникальное имя jar-файла формируется на основе трех слов которые указываются в полях groupId, artifactId и version. Но мне же надо чтобы имя было коротким и не содержало ненужной мне информации. Что-то на подобии этого "comp.jar". Я пробовал, но идея упорно ругается если поля оставлять пустыми или с пробелом. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете изменять конечное имя jar файла с помощью maven плагина:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myJar</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Для Maven >= 3**

```
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <build>
   <finalName>myJar</finalName>
 </build>
```